# Flask session-- Test case failure

Tags: python, flask, session, session-variables, flask-session

Working on storing login objects in session. Solution working fine on local machine. however test cases failing on hacker rank environment.
Steps followed :

- login page created to accept username and password
- routes created to save information from form as session object

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
{% block content %}
<!-- write a condition to check if the user in session or not with appropriate response and redirect routes-->
{% if login %}
    Logged in as {{ session['username'] }} 
    <a href="/logout">logout</a>
    {%else%}
    You are not logged in
    <a href="/login">login</a>.
    {%endif %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

test.py

```
 def test_login_and_user_page(self):
        soup1 = self.get_soup1()
        msg = soup1.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        link = soup1.find('a')
        assert msg.text == 'Logged in as admin'
        assert link['href'] == '/logout'

        soup3 = self.get_soup3()
        assert soup3.text == "You've been logged out successfully!"

        soup4 = self.get_soup4()
        msg = soup4.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        assert msg.text == 'Logged in as user'

    def test_user_page(self):
        soup2 = self.get_soup2()
        msg = soup2.find('p', {'id': 'b'})
        link = soup2.find('a')
        assert msg.text == 'You are not logged in'
        assert link['href'] == '/login'
```

Test failure:

```
============================================== FAILURES ==============================================
_______________________________ Test_Webpage.test_login_and_user_page ________________________________

self = <tests.Test_Webpage object at 0x7f8baae8c198>

    def test_login_and_user_page(self):
        soup1 = self.get_soup1()
        msg = soup1.find('p', {'id': 'a'})
        link = soup1.find('a')
>       assert msg.text == 'Logged in as admin'
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: One thing i noticed is that in the `user.html` the `<p>` Tags around the Message are missing. As far as i can see in the test they filter for the `<p>` Tag so maybe this could solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i wrote in my comment, the testcases try to filter for an `<p>` Tag to get the Output on the Webpage:

```py
msg = soup2.find('p', {'id': 'a'}) # first testcase
msg = soup2.find('p', {'id': 'b'}) # second testcase
```

But on your `html` Template you just wrote the text down:

```html
Logged in as {{ session['username'] }} 
You are not logged in
```

if you put these messages into the `<p>` tags and give them the correct `id` it should work.

```html
<p id="a">Logged in as {{ session['username'] }}</p>
<p id="b">You are not logged in</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, test cases passed when I did the suggested changes.